# blazor: having the same component multiple times on the same page but with different results. how to retrieve in parent component?

Tags: html, blazor

I my parent component I am doing this:

```
<TextArea/>
<TextArea/>
<TextArea/>
```

TextArea itself looks like this:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavManager


<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button onclick="makeBold()">put bold</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <textarea class="custom-textarea" id="custom-textarea" @bind="result" placeholder="Deutsche Beschreibung" rows="5"></textarea>
        </td>    
    </tr>
</table>
<button @onclick="() => Finish()">finish</button>


@code {
    string result = "";

    private void Finish()
    {
        var x = result; 
    }
}
```

Now, I need to have the results of the textarea three times in my parent component. But ofc all results are different.

How can I retrieve the results with all of them being different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your TextArea component like this:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavManager


<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button onclick="makeBold()">put bold</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <textarea class="custom-textarea" id="custom-textarea" @bind="result" placeholder="Deutsche Beschreibung" rows="5"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button @onclick="() => FinishAsync()">finish</button>


@code {
    [Parameter] public required string Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public required EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    
    private string result = "";

    private void FinishAsync()
    {
        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(result);
    }
}
```

Then you can use like this in your parent component:

```
<TextArea @bind-Value="Value1"></TextArea>
<TextArea @bind-Value="Value2"></TextArea>
<TextArea @bind-Value="Value3"></TextArea>

@code {
    private string Value1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private string Value2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private string Value3 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```